# How to remove garbage values from csv file?

Tags: java, eclipse, csv

I have a CSV file with some data and it also has a lot of invalid data in it. How can I print only the valid data and leave rest of it?

My data is like this:-

```
1,Ron,1234,XYZ
2,Harry,214,SDA
3,Kent,1786,GHI
SAMNE:MANNS;ndndo
kdbg;obmgdf;brhj
```

I want to print only the first 3 lines and remove the last two invalid lines. I am doing this in Eclipse.

Comment: How do you define a valid row?

Comment: Consider a valid row as such:- S.No,Name,Num, Company

Comment: valid means rows starting with integer followed ',' ?

Comment: @Shamik Yeah starting with integer

Comment: Then parse each line and check if it starts with an integer, if then print it.

Comment: You should use regex to check if is valid,I post an example

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this.

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("~/input.csv")));
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
        try{

            int sno = Integer.parseInt( line.split(",")[0]);
            System.out.println("Valid "+ line);
            //Continue doing more checks or other operations 

        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            //Skip invalid line  
            System.out.println("Invalid row "+ line);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check by regex if is valid, throw an exception  is a bad idea.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("~/input.csv")));
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
    if(line.matches("(\\d+,\\w+,\\d+,\\w+)"){
       print line;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                String[] part = line.split(",");
                try {
                    Integer.parseInt(part[0]);
                    System.out.println(line);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    // This is not a valid line
                }
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```